# How are "mvn clean package" and "mvn clean install" different?

Tags: java, maven

What exactly are the differences between `mvn clean package` and `mvn clean install`? When I run both of these commands, they both seem to do the same thing.

Comment: Please look at [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle - Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) and looking for `package` and `install` .

Comment: One packages (builds it in target) and on installs (packages and places it in you repository)  You need to do the later if you want to use this version in another module.

Comment: Perhaps this should be reopened?  It's perfectly possible to answer and I didn't find it difficult to answer.  Also, if someone is brand new to maven, it's easy to see how the two phases appear to do the same thing.  I'll edit it in an attempt to make it less vague.

Answer (score 564):

Well, both will clean.  That means they'll remove the target folder.   The real question is what's the difference between package and install?

`package` will compile your code and also package it.  For example, if your pom says the project is a jar, it will create a jar for you when you package it and put it somewhere in the target directory (by default).

`install` will compile and package, but it will also put the package in your local repository.  This will make it so other projects can refer to it and grab it from your local repository.

[Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Why is mvn install faster than mvn package then ?

Comment: @SharadHolani because builds are incremental. `mvn clean install` is not faster than `mvn package`.

Comment: For my project, mvn package assembly:single which builds the fat jar takes longer than a mvn install.

Do package and install both build equivalent fat jars ?

Comment: @RakeshYadav yes it does

Answer (score 380):

What clean does (common in both the commands) - removes all files generated by the previous build

---

Coming to the difference between the commands **package** and **install**, you first need to understand the ***lifecycle of a maven project***

---

These are the default life cycle phases in maven

- **validate** - validate the project is correct and all necessary information is available
- **compile** - compile the source code of the project
- **test** - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed
- **package** - take the compiled code and package it in its distributable format, such as a JAR.
- **verify** - run any checks on results of integration tests to ensure quality criteria are met
- **install** - install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally
- **deploy** - done in the build environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

---

How Maven works is, if you run a command for any of the lifecycle phases, it executes each default life cycle phase in order, before executing the command itself.

order of execution

> validate >> compile >> test (optional) >> package >> verify >> install >> deploy

So when you run the command ***mvn package***, it runs the commands for all lifecycle phases till package

> validate >> compile >> test (optional) >> package

And as for ***mvn install***, it runs the commands for all lifecycle phases till install, which includes package as well

> validate >> compile >> test (optional) >> package >> verify >> install

---

So, effectively what it means is, **install** commands does everything that **package** command does and some more (install the package into the local repository, for use as a dependency in other projects locally)

Source: [Maven lifecycle reference](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

Comment: This should be marked as accepted answer. This clearly defines and helps the OP to understand what the different phases of maven lifecycle and why mvn install includes mvn package but not the other way around.

Answer (score 28):

**package** will generate Jar/war as per POM file.
**install** will install generated jar file to the local repository for other dependencies if any.

**install** phase comes after **package** phase

Comment: first packaging will happen then those packages (jar/war) will install.

Comment: "Install phase _follows_ package phase". The way it's currently phrased is backwards. "Followed by" means "after".

Answer (score 20):

`package` will add packaged `jar` or `war` to your  `target` folder, We can check it when, we empty the target folder (using  `mvn clean`) and then run `mvn package`.

`install` will do all the things that `package` does, additionally it will add packaged `jar` or `war` in local repository as well. We can confirm it by checking in your `.m2` folder.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to check the .m2 folder

Answer (score 11):

Package & install are various phases in maven build lifecycle. package phase will execute all phases prior to that & it will stop with packaging the project as a jar. Similarly install phase will execute all prior phases & finally install the project locally for other dependent projects.

For understanding maven build lifecycle please go through the following link https://ayolajayamaha.blogspot.in/2014/05/difference-between-mvn-clean-install.html

Comment: What do you mean by " & finally install the project locally for other dependent projects "

Comment: @ArunGowda it means in the .m2 which is created in your system upon installing of the maven will be added with projects you are packaging and will be available for other projects as dependency.

Comment: a picture is a 1000 words, anyone got a diagram?

Comment: @MrCholo *mvn install* will put the jar/war into your maven repo.  The place where all your maven dependencies get stored, usually ~/.m2

Answer (score 6):

mvn package command will compile source code and also package it as a jar or war as per pom file and put it into the target folder(by default).

mvn install command will compile and package, but it will also put the package in your local repository. So that other projects can refer to it and grab it from your local repository.

mvn install command is mostly used when you wants to compile a project(library) which other projects in your repository are depending on.