# Maven Copy Folder Before War File Generation

Tags: java, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I have two Git repositories. One repositary is java services (maven web project) and another repository consists of UI {HTML, JS, CSS}(non maven), At the time of java services repository build I want to include the latest UI (master) into the war file. I tried with `maven-resources-plugin`

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>/home/srinivas/AAA/bb/</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

> mvn install

It copies the resources to target folder but it is not placing them in the war file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong phase in your execution as the `package` phase is actually the phase where your war is created, so you need to execute at an earlier phase e.g. `prepare-package`.

You should definitely read [Introduction to the Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for clarification.

In addition you should not become accustomed to pulling in resources via maven-resources-plugin from the file system. This is generally frowned upon as bad practice since other developers will not be able to reproduce your build.

Using a repository manager to store your dependencies is the way to go here. Read [Why do I need a Repository Manager?](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) to get started.

Comment: But the dependent repo is no a maven project

Comment: Even then you may choose to upload the war artifact to your local repository. Most repository managers allow such an operation via their GUI.

Comment: Yes, you can store zip artifacts in the repository and unpack those.

Comment: can you give some references

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html describes that.

Answer (score 0):

at first glance, change :

```
<phase>install</phase>
```

to

```
<phase>prepare-package</phase>
```

Comment: not bad to set phase to install instead of package. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602017/differences-between-the-commands-mvn-clean-package-and-mvn-clean-install