# How to reference sibling module in a test for my maven spring boot multi-module project?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, multi-module

**How can I include a sibling module as a test dependency for my spring boot tests in maven?**

I have a little multi-module maven project with a spring boot web app (**querying-api** ), a common library (**domain-definitions**), and an initializing script (**database-loader**).

I'm writing test cases in my **querying-api** module to test my API, and I would like to run my **database-loader** service before the tests begin to load the database with predefined test data, simultaneously testing that the loader still works. However I'm getting the following error when running `mvn clean package`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project querying-api: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my.little.package:querying-api:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find com.my.little.package:database-loader:jar:1.0.0 in http://mycompanysnexusrepo.com/nexus/content/repositories/EAJAVA/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of EAJAVA has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

The tests have no problem referencing the common **domain-definitions** library...

---

**Parent POM File:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>my-little-project</name>
    <description>Project for my little microservice</description>
    <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-little-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.security.version>2.3.5.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <springfox.version>2.7.0</springfox.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>domain-definitions</module>
        <module>database-loader</module>
        <module>querying-api</module>
    </modules>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>EAJAVA</id>
            <url>http://mycompanysnexusrepo.com/nexus/content/repositories/EAJAVA/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
                <artifactId>domain-definitions</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
                <artifactId>database-loader</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

---

**querying-api** POM file (Spring boot app for querying the database):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>querying-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>querying-api</name>
    <description>Spring boot app for querying the database</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-little-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain-definitions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
            <artifactId>database-loader</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>querying-api</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

**domain-definitions** POM file (Common library):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-little-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>domain-definitions</artifactId>
    <name>domain-definitions</name>
    <description>Classes to define the structure of the tables</description>
</project>
```

---

**database-loader** POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>database-loader</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>database-loader</name>
    <description>Java script to load data into the database for the first time</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-little-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain-definitions</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the library jar not found in the local repository. You need to first execute :
`mvn clean install`. 
This will install the lib jar in your local repository and maven can easily find it when you execute **package** goal.

Explained here: [How are "mvn clean package" and "mvn clean install" different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602017/how-are-mvn-clean-package-and-mvn-clean-install-different)

Furthermore, if you are using the sibling module only in tests then you can define the scope as **test** in dependency.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.my.little.package</groupId>
        <artifactId>domain-definitions</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry if my post wasn't clear, the library `domain-definitions` is working just fine. And I am able to include it as a dependency in my app `querying-api` without needing to first run `mvn clean install`. But for some reason, the java script `database-loader` can't be imported as a test dependency. I can't figure out why I'm able to import `domain-definitions` without an issue, but not `database-loader`, via `mvn clean package`.