# What is the difference between `mvn clean install` and `mvn clean package -Pbuild-image` in Spring Boot with the usage of Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven

I want to ask a question for what difference between `mvn clean install` and `mvn clean package -Pbuild-image` is when I create a **image** to be deployed **Docker** for running it as a **container**.

I use generally use `mvn clean install` and I notice that this command named `mvn clean package -Pbuild-image` is also used for this purpose.

Can you explain its difference? What is the `-Pbuild-image` ? Can you share its explanation?

Answer (score 1):

`clean install` compiles the source code, runs the tests (unless disabled using `-DskipTests`), packages the application, and installs to the local repository (a bunch of directories and files in the `.m2` directory on your disk).

On the other hand `clean package -Pbuild-image` runs `clean package` with the `build-image` profile. I assume you know the difference between `package` and `install` (otherwise, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602017/how-are-mvn-clean-package-and-mvn-clean-install-different)). This is where the difference ends from the Maven's perspective.

Maven knows nothing about any profile unless there is any functionality bound to it. Until then, the command is effectively equal to `clean package`. Once you place a plugin execution under such a profile, then additional things start to happen depending on the configuration (what) and execution phase (when). Here is a sample profile `build-image` with the plugin execution in the `package` phase taken from https://piotrminkowski.com/2023/05/26/spring-boot-development-mode-with-testcontainers-and-docker/:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>build-image</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <to>
            <image>sample-spring-microservices-advanced/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</image>
          </to>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>dockerBuild</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to explain `-Pbuild-image` with adding its documentation?

Comment: It is just a custom profile, nothing else. Even if you name it as `jumping-cow` and put the plugin execution under that, the behavior is the same. Search for "Maven Profiles".